# Boot problems in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, virtualbox, 18.04

I am just learning to use Ubuntu.I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using Oracle Virtual Box in  Windows 10. It was working fine till today. Just moments ago, I installed docker container using the terminal. After installation, I restarted the Virtual machine and it is struck in start-up page, which has violet background with ubuntu at the center (4 white dots and 1 red dot(if it is of any use)). It has 8192 MB base memory and is assigned 3 CPU processors. Is it somehow possible to restore the virtual machine or do I have to start-over?

I restarted the system multiple times.Now, I am able to login to Ubuntu. I don't know if it is a bug 
 Do delete this post if no one else has faced such issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: It happened again. Puzzled why it resurfaced. I don't want to create a new user. Anyone?